# vbscript to run command

Tags: command-line, vbscript

I'm trying to create a script that runs the command: `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255`

Right now this errors out

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sEXE = """C:\Windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255 """ 

        with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
          .Run sEXE & " " , 1, true
end with

        Wscript.Quit
```

Any suggestions? Could I make the script so I could run a bunch of commands and  wait until each process executed has finished before executing the other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line should appear exactly as it would if you typed it at the command prompt (verify by `Wscript.Echo sEXE`):

```
sEXE = """C:\Windows\system32\RunDll32.exe"" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"
```